# Building C++ binaries that work on RHEL and SLES

Tags: c++, centos, compatibility, opensuse

I need to build a single binary from C++ code that can run on RedHat and SuSE distribution. I need to distribute the binary, because I can't share the sources. Operating within these constraints I figured that one way would be to ship a compatible version of libstdc++ with my binary and have it link against it using rpath or ldconfig.

1. Is compat-libstdc++ of any use in this situation? What does it do?
2. Given say Centos / RHEL 7 and OpenSuSE / SLES 11, how do I figure out which is a compatible libstdc++ version that works on both OSs?

I can't link statically for a number of reasons, including derivative work clauses in LGPL, etc.

Comment: Compile a static binary?

Comment: Updated the question with why I cannot link statically.

Answer (score 0):

When you distribute binaries for different linux distributions you could put all depended libraries (including libstdc++) into a package with your binaries - you also could set RPATH to $ORIGIN in your binary so it will look for libraries in directory with your binary. That way it will work with most linux distros.

Comment: I build a single binary - not different versions of it for different distributions. It's an unusual constraint but that's how it is.

Comment: @CppNoob - well, if you cannot distribute anything beside 1 file, it wouldn't help. but I'm talking about single package (binary + libs) which works on different distros, not about different packages.

Comment: The question is more about libstdc++ versions and ABI compatibility across distributions. I understand how rpath works, but which versions of libstdc++ should I include - that's the question. What's the general strategy for identifying the version - given the target distros and versions, that's the question.